# SQL SELECT using a variable condition after WHERE

Tags: asp.net, mysql, variables, select, where-clause

I am using ASP.NET with the Webpages model and have created a database for users to post to, which is all great, then I created a page so users can edit their posts, however I want it so users can only edit their own posts.

To do this, I tried the following:

I made a variable

```
var EmailMatch = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
```

so if I put @EmailMatch anywhere in the html markup it will display the email address of the user who is currently logged in.  Now in order to display only the posts that this user has made, I used this select statement:

```
var selectAllString = "SELECT * FROM SaleData WHERE Email = '@EmailMatch'";
```

In theory I am thinking this should work, because when the user makes a post it sends their email address to the database under the field 'Email' and it should display records that are equal to the user currently logged in.  However this statement returns 0 results, I have tried all I can think of with no success, this is my last resort, can someone please tell me what I am missing? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is through parameterized queries.  Never ever concat strings that you do not have control over in to a query.

```
var EmailMatch = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
var selectAllString = "SELECT * FROM SaleData WHERE Email = @EmailMatch";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailMatch", EmailMatch);
var resultsTable = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: The relevant point here being that you don't need quotes around '@EmailMatch'

Comment: @MichaelBray - you are absolutely correct -  I should have mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply, but this code is giving me this error that im not familiar with: 'CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SqlCommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: @Ben - it will be located in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace - this is for SQL Server.  For other DBs, use the SqlCommand provided in the dll provided

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectAllString = "SELECT * FROM SaleData WHERE Email = '" + EmailMatch + "'";
```

Note: This could possibly expose you to SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var selectAllString = "SELECT * FROM SaleData WHERE Email = '"+EmailMatch+"'";
```

or to avoid SQL Injecton, your SQL statement is correct but you have to add this in your code:

```
using (OleDbConnection CON = new OleDbConnection("your connection string")) {
   OleDbCommand Com = CON.CreateCommand();
   Com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SaleData WHERE Email = @EmailMatch";
        Com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Com.CommandTimeout = 0;
        Com.Connection.Open();
        Com.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmailMatch",EmailMatch);
   ...
   // continue your code from here... 
}
```

Comment: Your command type is StoredProcedure, yet you are providing an sql select statement.  your command type should be CommandType.Text

Comment: the code that leaves me at risk of sql injection works, but yes, leaves the site open.. when i tried to add the extra code it returned this error:  'CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OleDbConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: what data provider are you using? OleDbConnection can be used if you are using MSAccess or MSSQL

Comment: add this reference `using System.Data.OleDb`

Comment: I pretty sure I'm using MSSQL, whichever goes with Webmatrix 2.. Sorry, I am a beginner with this, all these answers are very different and it's hard to follow the logic. I still can't get it to work, I need to do more research I guess, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SaleData WHERE Email = @EmailMatch", MySqlConn.conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailMatch", EmailMatch);
cmd.Prepare();
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: thanks, but this code tells me an error: 'CS0103: The name 'cmd' does not exist in the current context'